# Redirect page traffic to new urls in asp.net appllication

Tags: asp.net, wordpress, redirect, http-status-code-301, sitefinity

I have a WordPress site. which is now moving to asp.net cms (Sitefinity). In this process my url structures are getting changed but I want to keep the traffic of previous urls on the new urls as well.

Old as the domain will be transferred to new site old pages will not be found (404)

Things making it complicated.

- Old and new site has lots of Dynamic urls
- Old site has different urls structure than new url
- I do not wan't to put all these urls in web.config file.

Solutions I tried

- I tried to write 301 redirect on Robot.txt as I can capture old and new url at the time of migration
- I searched for solutions all over net but didn't got any straight forward solutions

  - One of the [forums](http://smepals.com/google-panda/when-use-robots-txt-301-redirects-panda-seo-recovery) mentioned that we should not write 301 redirects on Robot.txt

Don't know what to follow or where to search. Please guide me to correct path.

Thank You
Chandresh

Comment: Robots.txt is just for bots, it will not help users who have bookmarked the old URL. Either use URL Rewrite or as Jon R. said try to add the old url as an Additional URL for the Sitefinity item.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an identifiable pattern between the two using the URL rewrite module would be your best bet. Or write some code to insert the old urls as multiple URLs on the content items.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an example of the old URL and what the new URL will look like?  It is possible that if you know how the URL pattern will change you can create a redirect rule in your web.config.

Also, Sitefinity allows you to create redirects as well.  This includes creating alternative urls for pages or creating redirecting pages.

The exact solution really depends on how much the URL is changing and how many redirect urls are needed.